# How to get Outlook PST Name from Selected Mail VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, windows-7, outlook, office-interop

I had a situation where I want to get pst name based on selection made to an item in the Outlook explorer. Basically my Outlook has many inboxes. I need to have the name of the pst of the email item that I selected into.
So far I tried many iterations but no luck like basically I am from VBA back ground and in VBA I get it very easily like below:

```
oMailItem.Parent.Parent
```

and it gives me perfect result.
However, in .NET I don't see `oMailItem.Parent.Parent` when I put the dot after first `Parent`, IntelliSense does not offer a property `Parent` again. I tried conversion but no luck as I am very new to VB.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property [Parent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff863655.aspx) is of type `Object`, so you have to first cast it to `Outlook.Folder` like so. Keep in mind though that the conversion may not be possible and so you should check whether `folder` refers actually to an object and is not `Nothing`

```
Dim folder As Outlook.Folder = TryCast(oMailItem.Parent, Outlook.Folder)
If folder IsNot Nothing Then
    folder.Parent ...
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your response let me try

Comment: Hi, i tried code and able to cast the object but how would i get path of the folder as i tried this Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder
            oFolder = TryCast(oItem.Parent, Outlook.Folder)
            If oFolder IsNot Nothing Then
                oFolder.Parent.ToString()
            End If

Comment: I need to achieve root folder from this chain. I traverse through the oFolder object and under Dynamic View i see it gives me "My PS Name\Inbox\PersonalFolder"

Comment: If you need the root folder, why not going up the next level until there is no parent folder any longer? So essentially casting the folder.Parent again to Outlook.Folder as long as it does not return Nothing at which point you should have reached the root.

Comment: In case you need the 'path' as string you may want to try https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.folderclass.fullfolderpath.aspx - But I did not test it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Store.FilePath`. To get the parent store, use `MAPIFolder.Store`. To get the parent folder, read the `MailItem.Parent` property and cast it to `MAPIFolder`.